# \Include{MyFile} not including

Tags: include

To make my `main.txt` more readable I want to use `\include{titlepage}` where `titlepage` is saved in the same folder as `main.txt`. I also used `\include` for my file `Chapter1.txt` that works perfect, so something must be wrong in `titlepage` (right)?

`titlepage.txt` looks like this

```
%titlepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.75\linewidth}
    \centering
%University logo
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{unilogo.png}
    % \rule{0.4\linewidth}{0.15\linewidth}\par
   \par
   \vspace{3cm}
%Thesis title
    {\uppercase{\Large the title of my thesis project which may span multiple lines\par}}
    \vspace{3cm}
%Author's name
    {\Large Your name\par}
    \vspace{3cm}
%Degree
    {\Large A thesis submitted for the degree of Doctor of Philosophy\par}
    \vspace{3cm}
%Date
    {\Large May 2014}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
%\clearpage
```

Comment: Hmmm, `\include` expects a `.tex` file, not a `.txt` file. Are you sure about your file extensions? What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: That solved the issue. Thanks! I'm so used to saving .txt that I didn't notice that the last two letter changed place. This is a sign for me to end the day :)

Answer (score 3):

`\include{<file>}` expects `<file>.tex` to be available, not `<file>.txt`, so rename your files to match the `.tex` extension.

Here's an extract showing the definition of `\include` from the LaTeX kernel [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx):

```
\def\include#1{\relax
  \ifnum\@auxout=\@partaux
    \@latex@error{\string\include\space cannot be nested}\@eha
  \else \@include#1 \fi}
\def\@include#1 {%
  \clearpage
  \if@filesw
    \immediate\write\@mainaux{\string\@input{#1.aux}}%
  \fi
  \@tempswatrue
  \if@partsw
    \@tempswafalse
    \edef\reserved@b{#1}%
    \@for\reserved@a:=\@partlist\do
      {\ifx\reserved@a\reserved@b\@tempswatrue\fi}%
  \fi
  \if@tempswa
    \let\@auxout\@partaux
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\openout\@partaux #1.aux
      \immediate\write\@partaux{\relax}%
    \fi
    \@input@{#1.tex}% <------------------------------------ .tex extension added
    \clearpage
    \@writeckpt{#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \immediate\closeout\@partaux
    \fi
  \else
    \deadcycles\z@
    \@nameuse{cp@#1}%
  \fi
  \let\@auxout\@mainaux}
```

The subsidiare `\@include` is called from `\include`, and later on does `\@input@{#1.tex}` (highlighted above), implying the `.tex` extension.

Comment: Hmm, I would not have expected this behavior, but so it is.